# Temporary object-pool for unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, memory-management, garbage-collection, virtualization

I am running a large unit test repository for a complex project.
This project has some things that don't play well with large test amounts:

1. caches (memoization) that cause objects not to be freed between tests
2. complex objects at module level that are singletons and might gather data when being used

I am interested in each test (or at least each test suite) having its own "python-object-pool" and being able to free it after.

Sort of a python-garbage-collector-problem workaround.

I imagine a python self-contained temporary and discardable interpreter that can run certain code for me and after i can call "interpreter.free()" and be assured it doesn't leak.

One tough solution for this I found is to use Nose or implement this via subprocess for each time I need an expendable interpreter that will run a test. So each test becomes "fork_and_run(conditions)" and leaks no memory in the original process.

Also saw Nose single process per each test and run the tests sequantially - though people mentioned it sometimes freezes midway - less fun..

Is there a simpler solution?

P.S.
I am not interested in going through vast amounts of other peoples code and trying to make all their caches/objects/projects be perfectly memory-managed objects that can be cleaned.

P.P.S
Our PROD code also creates a new process for each job, which is very comfortable since we don't have to mess around with "surviving forever" and other scary stories.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
Module reload trick I tried worked locally, broke when used on a machine with a different python version... (?!)

I ended up taking any and all caches I wrote in code and adding them to a global cache list - then clearing them between tests.
Sadly this will break if anyone uses a cache/manual cache mechanism and misses this, tests will start growing in memory again...

For starters I wrote a loop that goes over sys.modules dict and reloads (loops twice) all modules of my code. this worked amazingly - all references were freed properly, but it seems it cannot be used in production/serious code for multiple reasons:

1. old python versions break when reloading and classes that inherit meta-classes are redefined (I still don't get how this breaks).
2. unit tests survive the reload and sometimes have bad instances to old classes - especially if the class uses another classes instance. Think super(class_name, self) where self is the previously defined class, and now class_name is the redefined-same-name-class.